# Setting url of an existing repo to a new one already having initial commit

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am migrating my existing repo to a new one.

My existing repo : orgRepo.git

New repo : newRepo.git

I know that :
Cd orgRepo/callsheet/
git set-url remote newRepo.git
Git -push origin -all
Git -push tags

The above set of commands would have worked if my new repo has no initial commit to master but that's not the case.

My newRepo.git has an initial commit and now I want to move everything inside a directory (callsheet) including commits tags etc under orgRepo.git to my newRepo.git.

It rejects the push, giving the error tip of the current branch is behind.

I have tried the above commands, plus setting the remote as initial repo in the newRepo.
I have also tried to set the url of oldRepo.git to the feature branch checked out from newRepo.git

I tried rebasing and all as well but nothing seems to work.

Comment: How much code has been changed? Might be better to just use a new folder for the new repo, pull the initial commit and copy the changes to a new branch on that repo.

Comment: No, the initial commit contains one text file only. orgRepo.git has a folder called callsheet which needs to be pushed to this repo..as well as I need to set the url of org repo to new repo.

Comment: If that's all, then copy and check in the text file to the existing repo, update the remote URL and then force push the local branch to the remote. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---force